# REPLACE WITH NVL

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, numbers, nvl

```
select to_number(replace(nvl('-100,000',0),'',','),'999,999,999.99')from dual;
```

... produces the output: 100000

Now I use the same expression in my procedure with table column:

```
select to_number(replace(nvl(TABLEA.VOLUME,0),'',','),'999,999,999.99')from TABLEA;
```

... and get the output: INVALID NUMBER

Column `VOLUME` in `TABLEA` is of type `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: This means you have some values in TABLEA.VOLUME which cannot be cast to numbers.

Comment: You are getting the error as all the values in `TABLEA` might not be a number format that you are expecting.

Comment: Hi Tejash-- I got this exception ORA-01722: invalid number

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly the contents of column `VOLUME` are stored as strings without the grouping character ( `,` ). Thus the strings violate the format in the conversion with `to_number`.

In addition, the argument order in `REPLACE` makes no sense.

Finally, you want to swap the calls to `NVL` and `REPLACE`.

So - assuming that you want to parse numbers with 2 fractional digits given as strings - use the following:

```
select to_number ( nvl ( replace (TABLEA.VOLUME, ',', ''), 0), '999999999.99') from TABLEA;
```

Comment: select to_number ( nvl ( replace (10,000, ',', ''), 0), '999999999.99') from DUAL;
--it's not working

Comment: ORA-00939-TOO MAY ARGUMENTS FOR FUNCTION

Comment: @aishwaryam Yes, your syntax is wrong: The first argument to `replace` should be a string and if you want to exploit auto-conversion from number then don't use a grouping character (`,`) in your number. ( see it yourself: `select to_number ( nvl ( replace ('10,000', ',', ''), 0), '999999999.99') from DUAL;` works)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to convert the string values to money format.

First, consider replace as you did by switching `''` and `','` parameters in the argument order to remove the commas, and making suitable for numeric conversion as :

`to_number(replace(nvl(str,0),',',''))`,

and then apply the money format as :

```
with tableA as
(
 select '-100,000' as volume
   from dual
)
select to_char( 
                to_number(replace(nvl(volume,0),',','')) 
              ,'fm999G999G990D00','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')
       as Money
  from tableA;


MONEY
-----------
-100,000.00
```

Depending on the currency displaying style the order of dot and comma can be switched as
`'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'''` to display the money as `-100.000,00`.

*P.S. first of all, you need to make sure all the data for `volume` column can be casted to number to be able to use `to_number()` conversion.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f042104edac970a83701b1655c629299)</kbd>